# create a daily time series data from stock market value taking five days in a week

Tags: r, time-series

I am exploring a daily stock market **Close** values available in google finance. I want to apply some time series techniques over that data. The data is available for Monday to Friday except the weekends.

I don't know how to represent this kind of time series data as `ts()` object with weekly frequency 5. I have 3 years of data (some missing values are there) and start date is on Monday and end date is Friday.

Please help me to create this `ts()` object.

Comment: This doesn't directly answer your question, but here's a link with some background information that might be applicable: http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2015/09/reading-financial-time-series-with-r.html